# What is the term for a thing instantiated by saying it?

Tags: terminology

A promise comes into existence merely by saying it. What is the term for a thing, or property of a thing, that is instantiated by saying or naming it?

Comment: Constitutive? “I now wed thee” constitutes becoming married in the right contexts.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you are in the neighborhood of "speech acts". "Illocutionary act" refers to "what was done by speaking", such as requesting. A subtype is performatives (or declarations) such as "I pronounce you man and wife", "I sentence you to 30 years", "I divorce thee" (uttered according to the triple talaq formula), "I name you Velma", "I curse you".

Comment: Perhaps that is what I'm thinking of. More specifically, what if a property is conferred by a possibly nonverbal declaration. For example, in a domain where objective standards are vague or nonexistent, an object is deemed good by the judgement of a recognized expert member. That judgement might be verbal, or might even be conferred nonverbally by successfully selling the object.

Comment: Read H. P. Grice _Logic and Conversation_. In it he posits the concept of a _performative_, which is a speech act that relies on specific formulas. Promises, assertions, questions, blessings, curses, baptisms, marriages, ... etc.

Comment: "How to Do Things with Words", by J. L. Austin is another good text.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps “invocation”

E.g. “I invoke the 5th amendments protection agains self-incrimination.”